# how to define event for keyPressed/keyCode...?

Tags: keypress, keycode

A freshman here that's stuck and confused on an assignment..
I'm surely doing it wrong because I get error on keyPressed as event is not define, with the code below. How do I define event in this instances?...

```
function keyPressed()
{ console.log("keyPressed");
//  When any key is pressed:
//  - Make RestrictedSafeComb2 equal to the value of 'keyCode'
 event.keyCode = 'enter'
 RestrictedSafeComb2 = event.keyCode;
}
```

Comment: Thera is  an example in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `keypress` event is deprecated. I am not sure what the nature of your assignment is, but you might go ahead with `keydown` instead.

Also `keydown` is the event you want your code to watch for and use its properties. I presume `KeyboardEvent.code` is what you want.

More details on MDN Web Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', keyPressed);
function keyPressed(e) {
  console.log (e.code)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```